# How to toggle a Boolean on checkbox in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on the following code. How can I toggle the state of the Boolean, here `isChecked` through controller in Angularjs checkbox?

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="checkController">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="choice" name="item" ng-change="changeSta(choice)" /> Add New Item
  </div>
</body>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('checkController', function($scope) {
   var isChecked = false;
   $scope.changeSta = function() {
     //isChecked = true;
  };

});

</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs, it exactly describes what you're looking for https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: Just the change the model itself ($scope.choice = true or false).

Comment: Why not just use `$scope.choice` instead of having a separate `isChecked` variable? If you do that then you probably don't need `ng-change` or the `changeSta` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check for the changes in your checkbox model:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('checkController', function($scope) {
    var isChecked = false;
    $scope.changeSta = function() {
        console.log($scope.choice);
    };
```